# How to use updateItem to update read and flag proerties at the same time

Tags: exchangewebservices

For developing mail functions to access exchange server, I use API of 'UpdateItem' to update mails' read&flag properties, send xml request as below,
but the server returned response with error of 'a:ErrorInvalidRequest'.

How can I update the item's read&flag properties by using 'UpdateItem' in one request?

'UpdateItem' API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/updateitem-operation

```
              <t:ItemChange>
                    <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADE06AAA=" />
                    <t:Updates>
                        <t:SetItemField>
                            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="message:IsRead" />
                            <t:Message>
                                <t:IsRead>false</t:IsRead>
                            </t:Message>
                        </t:SetItemField>
                        <t:SetItemField>
                            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Flag" />
                            <t:Message>
                                <t:Flag>
                                    <t:FlagStatus>false</t:FlagStatus>
                                </t:Flag>
                            </t:Message>
                        </t:SetItemField>
                    </t:Updates>
                </t:ItemChange>
```

Comment: Please include the specific framework and language you're using in your question. That way it's easier for others to find you question and answer it and it makes it easier for others who have your same issue to find your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding, I 've updated my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I find the cause, I have made a mistake in the flag part of my xml request, can't use 'false', but need to use '**NotFlagged**' .
I should write as below, it will works well

```
                       <t:SetItemField>
                            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Flag" />
                            <t:Message>
                                <t:Flag>
                                    <t:FlagStatus>NotFlagged</t:FlagStatus>
                                </t:Flag>
                            </t:Message>
                        </t:SetItemField>
```